# object of type 'slice' has no len()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Working this example from the Python for Finance book in Python 3 and getting this error.  My understanding is I need to use slice in order to have this range. Otherwise I need to use a tuple.

```
spo.brute(fo, (slice(-10, 10.1, 5)), (slice(-10, 10.1, 5)), finish=None)

TypeError: object of type 'slice' has no len()
```

Comment: is spa a list @michael-peterson?

Comment: @AndyK do you mean spo? it's a sublibrary in Scipy

Comment: [`slice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) vs [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)? Neither of those will support float arguments, so please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @dhke: `slice` actually does take float arguments - heck, [it takes anything](http://ideone.com/OHma0f) - but most things receiving a slice won't understand what to do with floats.

Comment: @user2357112 Well, I wrote "support" not "accept" for a reason: `slice(-10, 10.1, 5).indices(1)` => `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`

Comment: @dhke thank you both for the responses but do you mind providing an example of the correct syntax? I get what you're advising but the variations of syntax i'm trying aren't working. thx

Comment: @user2357112 thank you both for the responses but do you mind providing an example of the correct syntax? I get what you're advising but the variations of syntax i'm trying aren't working. thx

Comment: def fo(x, y):
    z = np.sin(x) + 0.05 * x ** 2 + np.sin(y) + 0.05 * y ** 2
    if output == True:
        print('%8.4f %8.4f %8.4f' % (x, y, z))
        return z

Comment: ^^^^ the fo func it's using

Comment: @MichaelPeterson: [I already did.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43688206/2357112)

Comment: @user2357112 spo.brute(fo, (slice(-10, 10.1, 5), slice(-10, 10.1, 5)), finish=None)               i updated per your answer and now getting TypeError: fo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Comment: @dhke A `slice` constructed with float parameters *can* be a valid index, provided that the object that's being indexed knows what to do with them. In the case of `scipy.optimize.brute`, [the slices are ultimately passed to `numpy.mgrid`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/0a721abff500de68bcbf339e6875bd6dd9d441be/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L2715), which [interprets these in a special way](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html), but in general most objects that support slice indexing won't handle floats as slice parameters.

Comment: @dhke i've made them all integers and now getting TypeError: fo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
output = True
ranges = (slice(-10, 10, 5), slice(-10, 10, 5))
spo.brute(fo, ranges, finish=None)

Comment: @MichaelPeterson You haven't shown us the signature for your objective function `fo`. Does it need more than one argument? If so then you'll need to pass in the additional arguments to `brute` using the `args=` parameter. See the docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html).

Comment: @ali_m Ah, live and learn. Thanks for the update.

Comment: def fo(x, y):
    z = np.sin(x) + 0.05 * x ** 2 + np.sin(y) + 0.05 * y ** 2
    if output == True:
        print ('%8.4f %8.4f %8.4f' % (x, y, z))
        return z

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing a tuple of two slices as the `ranges` argument to `scipy.optimize.brute`, you're passing one slice as `ranges` and another as `args`. You need to provide a tuple:

```
scipy.optimize.brute(fo, (slice(-10, 10.1, 5), slice(-10, 10.1, 5)), finish=None)
```

It may be clearer to define the tuple outside the function call:

```
ranges = (slice(-10, 10.1, 5), slice(-10, 10.1, 5))
scipy.optimize.brute(fo, ranges, finish=None)
```

Comment: your original example and the ranges variable both bring back TypeError: fo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Comment: @MichaelPeterson: Yeah, you've got more bugs.

Comment: yeah thanks for taking a look. working right from the book but published before 3. kinda frustrating but at least get the gist of the example